# django model save - override method not invoked during migrations

Tags: python, django, migration

I have a save override method in my model class, which generates a new slug each time an object is saved.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.column2:
        self.slug = slugify(self.column1 + " " + self.column2)
    else:
        self.slug = slugify(self.column1)
    print slug
    super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

When I try to create a new object by logging into the python shell, I see the save method is being invoked.

```
python manage.py shell

>>> MyModel(column1="test",column2="2015").save()
slug is test-2015
```

However when I am running a migration, this save override method is not being called. Here's part of my migration script..

```
...
def add_myModel_details(apps, schema_editor):
    x = apps.get_model("myapp","myModel")
    MyModel(column1 = "test", column2="2015" ).save()
.....
```

The slug is empty, as the save override isn't being called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because migrations don't call your `save` method.

I think save method is not the best place for generate slug. Will be better to use *AutoSlugField* or *signals*.

#### [1. signals:](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/signals/)

In your case you may use signal [pre_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.pre_save).

Example:

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=MyModel)
def my_handler(sender, **kwargs):
    my_model = kwargs.get('instance')
    if my_model.column2:
        my_model.slug = slugify(my_model.column1 + " " + my_model.column2)
    else:
        my_model.slug = slugify(my_model.column1)
    print my_model.slug
```

#### 2. AutoSlugField:

It's not a standard field but a lot of libraries implement it. I use *AutoSlugField* from [django-extensions](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions). This field uses [signals](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions/blob/master/django_extensions/db/fields/__init__.py#L179) too.

Example:

```
slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from=("column1", "column2"))
```

#### 3. `save` method and migrations

But if you still want to use a `save` method to generating slug I'd recommend you create data migration and add slugs manually.

[Data Migrations django >= 1.7](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/#data-migrations)

[Data Migrations south](https://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/part3.html#data-migrations)

Comment: IMHO the slug field should be assigned in the `save()` function and in case of changes, it should be manually called after migrations. E.g. `./manage.py shell -> for x in x.objects.all(): x.save()` since this allows the code related to saving to be present in the correct function, and the changes to be explicitly applied (in case of errors, etc. they can be detected and resolved)

Comment: Thanks @Kirill - I will check out the links. AutoSlugField looks interesting. I did take a look at it before and for some reason I can;t remember now, decided it doesn't suit my purpose. Will check the pre_save option.

Comment: @kicker86 - I got my migration to work by copying the slug logic into the migration as well, but your approach of calling save after the method has more code reusability. Thanks!

Comment: First signal approach will not work in data migrations actually. I tried this (Django 1.10), and signals also was not called. See this for details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26542617/how-can-i-send-signals-from-within-django-migrations

Comment: According to @kicker86 suggestion we can also implement custom `manage.py` command for this instead of datamigration, it is very easy:  http://maketips.net/tip/30/django-managepy-command

Answer (score 12):

Custom model methods are not available during migrations.

Instead, you can run put code in your `RunPython` function that modifies your model instances the way the custom `save()` would have.

## References:

- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37685925/247696)