# Django migration not calling overridden save() method?

Tags: python, django, database-migration

I have a model `SessionCategory` which is similar to the following:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.text import slugify


class SessionCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    name_slug = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.name_slug:
            self.name_slug = slugify(self.name)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

So the `name_slug` field, which I'd like to add, is a slugified version of the `name` field.

I've run the following data migration:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import migrations, models


def generate_name_slugs(apps, schema_editor):
    SessionType = apps.get_model('lucy_web', 'SessionType')
    for session_type in SessionType.objects.all():
        session_type.save()


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('lucy_web', '0163_auto_20180627_1309'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='sessioncategory',
            name='name_slug',
            field=models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True),
        ),
        migrations.RunPython(
            generate_name_slugs,
            reverse_code=migrations.RunPython.noop),
    ]
```

However, if I check the database afterward, the `name_slug` fields are all null:

[image]

I've also reversed the migration and re-run it setting a trace (`import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()`) in the overridden `save()` method, but it didn't cause Python to drop into the debugger, confirming that that method is not called.

Why is the overridden `save()` method not getting called? Do I have to replicate the code in the `generate_name_slugs` function?

Comment: `SessionType` in `generate_name_slugs` but `SessionCategory` in the select.

Comment: But quite apart from that, the class you get from `apps.get_model` is not the class in your models file, by design.

Comment: Similar: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28777338 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/32010854

Answer (score 2):

This should help for `SessionType`... `SessionCategory` can be modified the  same way...

```
def generate_name_slugs(apps, schema_editor):
    import lucy_web.models as m
    for session_type in m.SessionType.objects.all():
        session_type.save()
```